# How to cast VBox to extended class VBox?

Tags: java, class, javafx, fxml

I'm creating an application using JavaFX and FXML.

I have a class:

```
class Card extends VBox
{
    private String title;
    private String description;
    /* and so on ... */
}
```

And I have an instance of class `VBox`

```
VBox box = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("styled_vbox.fxml");
```

And I have an instance of class `Card`

```
Card card;
```

I want to cast the `box` object to the class `Card` which extends `VBox` class so that i can assign the `box` object to the `card` object.

Is it possible to do it? If yes, how can i do it?

Comment: What? I'm sorry, but this question is not very clear at all. Please take the [tour], read the guide on [ask] a good question and then [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're trying to do and where you need help.

Comment: @Zephyr ok sorry it's my first question.

Comment: You seem to be looking for [`fx:root`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#root_elements).

Comment: @Slaw yeah it seems it is. thanks a bunch.

Comment: You cannot cast an object to a subtype (= it's real type not the type of expression). If the root of the fxml is an ´<Card>´ element. If it's an `<Card>` element, casting or simply assigning directly when loading (`Card card = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("styled_vbox.fxml");`) should work.

Comment: @fabian the `fx:root` element did the trick for me but i'll try that idea too. thanks.